# How to set variable value based on a subrequest

Tags: web, nginx, server, auth-request

I am trying to set the value of a variable based on the result if the user is correctly logged in. I will use this variable for conditional ssi. I am using the `auth_request module` to authorise the user. This authorisation happens for all pages. The problem I am facing is that for 401/403 errors, NGINX passes `401` to the client. What I want to do is to show some pages anyway (even if the authorization fails), but set the variable (to the status of subrequest) for conditional ssi.

Config File

```
  location / {
    set $auth_status 100; #Default Value
    error_page 401 403 $show_anyway;
    error_page 500 = /auth_fallback;
    auth_request /auth_public;
    auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
    auth_request_set $show_anyway $request_uri;
  }

  location = /auth_public
  {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    #return 200; #Tried this, but sub request doesn't fire.  
  }
```

Comment: I guess, you need `auth_request_set` and `error_page` directives.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, I dont want to show some error_page, I want to show the requested page anyway with the variable set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`error_page 401 403 =200 ...` can help. I tested the following config

```
ssi on;

location / {
    set $auth_status 100;
    auth_request /auth.php;
    auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
    error_page 401 403 =200 @process;
}

location @process {
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location = /auth.php {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Note about try_files inside @process - `$uri/` droped for prevent internal redirect by `index` directive (if index file found). If internal redirect pass to `location /`, last error code will be used.

Comment: Thanks @terra, I'll try this out and let you know!

Comment: Thanks again @terra. Your solutions works like a charm. My mistake was not to convert 401/403 errors into 200.